# DataGridViewCell value being empty, while actually exist

Tags: c#, datagridview

I don't know anymore why this is happen?

```
var tradeList = client.getTradeReports(criteria);
tradeGridView.DataSource = tradeList;
int rowCount = tradeGridView.Rows.Count;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tradeGridView.Rows)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < columnNameAndFlag.Length; counter++)
    {
        if (row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value == null || row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value.ToString()))
            tradeData.Add("");
        else
        {
            if (columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0] == "TransactTime")
                tradeData.Add(dt.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value)).ToLocalTime().ToString());
            else
                tradeData.Add(row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value.ToString());
        }
     }
}
```

Everything just fine if I don't use foreach loop, the datagrid shows the data. But when I use foreach loop, every cells value return empty/null.

```
MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[anyColumn].Value.ToString()); // messagebox shows nothing
```

That's why only this line that meet condition:

```
if (row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value == null || row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value.ToString()))
```

EDIT:

This is how I create columns and set each new cell value with list manually:

```
List<string> tradeData = new List<string>();

string columnSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["columnSettings"];
string[] columnNameAndFlag = columnSettings.Split(',');

var tradeList = client.getTradeReports(criteria);
tradeGridView.DataSource = tradeList;
int rowCount = tradeGridView.Rows.Count;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tradeGridView.Rows)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < columnNameAndFlag.Length; counter++)
    {
        if (row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value == null || row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value.ToString()))
            tradeData.Add("");
        else
        {
            if (columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0] == "TransactTime")
                tradeData.Add(dt.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value)).ToLocalTime().ToString());
            else
                tradeData.Add(row.Cells[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}

tradeGridView.DataSource = null;
tradeGridView.Columns.Clear();

for (int counter = 0; counter < columnNameAndFlag.Length; counter++)
{
    tradeGridView.Columns.Add(columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0], columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]);

    if (columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-').Last() == "1")
        tradeGridView.Columns[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Visible = true;
    else
        tradeGridView.Columns[columnNameAndFlag[counter].Split('-')[0]].Visible = false;
}

for (int index = 0; index < rowCount; index++)
    tradeGridView.Rows.Add();

int i = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tradeGridView.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cell.Value = tradeData[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if `counter < columnNameAndFlag.Length;` is always 0? or thus counter actually increment but still shows no value.

Comment: @P. Pat yes, the counter is increment

Comment: You can debug that `foreach` loop and check actual value of cells you looping through. Code, you posted, should work.

Comment: @Fabio I did bro, and the error comes. It is weird as hell

Comment: Show the error - Error message, line where error throws

Comment: @Fabio If you see above, the only "if" line that meet condition is that. The result is, List<string> tradeData always filled by empty string. But I've tried to put a string variable to catch row.Cells[anyColumn].Value, and it return null

Comment: Then you need check that data was properly bounded to the `DataGridView`. For example if you have created columns manually - check that column names from `columnNameAndFlag` are same as column/property names in `tradeList`. What is type of `tradeList`?

Comment: @Fabio The type is List<TradeReport> and I've matched all columns name with columns I created manually..

Comment: @HobasMatius you stated above that cell values only return empty/null only if you use `foreach`. Is there a specific reason why you need to use `foreach`? Cause it can also be done with `for` loop only and instead of `rows.Cells` it just becomes `tradeGridView.Rows[counter]` which basically goes through all rows.

Comment: @HobasMatius - the fact that `row.Cells[anyColumn].Value` return `null` refer to that column `anyColumn` exists in `DataGridView` but contains no value. The reason is that `DataGridView.DataSource`(`TradeReport` in your case) doesn't have property with name which set in `DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName`(assumes that values are not `null`). So the problem is not in your loop, problem is in how data bounded to the `DataGridView`. If will show us properties of `TradeReport` and how you have created columns manually - we will be able to help you, unless you will see problem by yourself

Comment: Another suggestion - because you using data-binding - you ca easily loop through `List<TradeReport>` instead of looping `DataGridView` rows and unnecessarily converting values

Comment: Can you explain what you trying to achieve. You have `List<TradeReport>` - what final output you expecting? Does `columnNameAndFlag` contains names of the properties in `TradeReport` class(`"nameOfProperty1-1,nameOfProperty2-0"`)?

Comment: @Fabio `columnNameAndFlag` contains columns configuration from app.config file. 1 means the column will be visible, 0 invisible. `TradeReport` class contains properties like ID, TradeDate, Account, OrderID etc. I want to move data from `var tradeList` into `List<string> tradeData` but with some changes. Because I know, we are not allowed to make changes when we use data-bound

Comment: Can you show example of `List<TradeReport>`(1-3 rows) and expected result of `List<string>` for those trade report's rows

Comment: `List<TradeReport>` contains properties as I mentioned above. `List<string>` contains properties as `List<TradeReport>`, but in different order, it depends on user configuration. So if in `TradeReport` the order will be ID, Account, OrderID but in `tradeList` it should accomodate user configuration, it might Account, OrderID and then ID. That's why I collect first to `tradeList` and then do some modify, store it into `tradeData`, create column manually as user desire and then load from `tradeData` into my datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

you should write tradeGridView.DataBind(); command after tradeGridView.DataSource = tradeList; and check if it is working.

Comment: `DataGridView` is Winform control and doesn't have `.DataBind` method

Comment: Ok. It must be throwing exception of type casting since you datarow and datagridview rows are two different type.  Instead of iterating through data grid, you can iterate the dataset which you had filled.

Comment: @mBangali unfortunately I'm pretty sure that it is not about casting. It's just how come you got empty cell while actually it exist. It is as simple as that.